# android application crashes when instantiating stl map

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have been trying to use a library I wrote in c++ in an android application and its been crashing with illegal instruction error. I started commenting out parts of the code until nothing was left but member variables which are a stl vector and map.  So I try and directly call function that does nothing but create a map and when i did this the debugger in android studio stopped inside the constructor of the map. If i remove the map and do anything else like read some files from asset folder and return their  content as a string to java interface it works. Is there a way for me to continue using c++ maps because it seems that the android c++ runtime implementation is at fault here?

**log cat**

A/libc: Fatal signal 4 (SIGILL), code 2, fault addr 0x7f795a502e89 in tid 585

**crash message**

SIGILL (signal SIGILL: illegal instruction operand)

**jni code**

```
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_hasebou_MainActivity_test(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance){

std::map<int,int> hello;
}
```

**declaration in java**

```
public native void test();
```

Comment: Post the Java exception log or the C++ stack dump.  Most likely you don't have the JNI bindings right, or you forgot to load the .so library in Java.  Or possibly you didn't compile in STL support correctly

Comment: I loaded my library in the static Initializer using System.loadLibrary("native-lib"); where native-lib is the library I have written in c++. Furthermore, its seems that using std::vector doesn't cause a problem. Therefore I am assuming that I have stl support enabled.

Comment: I thought about switching the c++ runtime but I haven't been able to do so. I can find a website explaining how to create android.mk files and make android studio use them instead of the default android.mk.

Comment: @GabeSechan Its also worth nothing I have  chosen C++11 support from the android studio project creation dialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out enabling avx instructions caused the problem because android only supports SSE