# SEGILL android ndk code

Tags: android-ndk

I have developed a library which I have testing on an x86-64 bit machine and it works and passes tests successfully. When I put it in my android application, the code stops in a constructor that just initializes all its variables to their default values (pointers get assigned to null, booleans to false...). I have set the target for x86-64 bit so I am sure it's not a problem of deploying a different architecture. How can I find out the root of the problem because if I do comment out the initialization in the constructor, it will execute a good amount of code before giving a SEGILL error again? I am using android 8 x64 bit intel image in the emulator. Also, the log cat doesn't show anything, the only error is the SEGILL.

It seems  that most of the time, doing some pointer manipulation causes the  problem. Simply initializing pointers with null or new causes the app to crash.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android application crashes when instantiating stl map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49708856/android-application-crashes-when-instantiating-stl-map)

Comment: @DmitriiZ. the behavior has changed, it doesnt  crash on stl, so its not a duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of enabling SSE, I enabled avx which is not supported by android and therefore clang optimized some parts by using avx which resulted in SIGILL.